# Can I store the "destination" (i.e. SpanID.textContent) of a value in an array? (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've been trying to greatly shorten my  change calculator project to adhere to DRY (http://jsfiddle.net/hpqr6kg2/), but the big issue is that every loop needs to output to a different location in the HTML. Is there a way for me to store every location in an array, so if I make a function I can just loop a value through it?

**Some of My Code** (the rest is just the same stuff copied and pasted for the rest of the kinds of US currency).

```
var kindsOfCurrency = [20, 10, 5, 1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01]
            var moneyNeeded = changeNeeded
            console.log(moneyNeeded)

            for (var i = 0; moneyNeeded >= kindsOfCurrency[0]; i++) {
                moneyNeeded = moneyNeeded - kindsOfCurrency[0]
            };
                twentiesNeededHTML.textContent = i + " twenties, "
                moneyNeeded = (Math.round(100*moneyNeeded)/100)
                console.log(moneyNeeded)

            for (var i = 0; moneyNeeded >= kindsOfCurrency[1]; i++) {
                moneyNeeded = moneyNeeded - kindsOfCurrency[1]
            }
                tensNeededHTML.textContent = i + " tens, "
                moneyNeeded = (Math.round(100*moneyNeeded)/100)
                console.log(moneyNeeded)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all the Element IDs in a array, such as:

```
   var elementIDs = ["twentiesNeededHTML", "tensNeededHTML", ...]
```

Then loop through the array

```
for (var i = 0; i < elementsIDs.length; i++) {

    //Whatever code is comming before

    document.getElementById(elementsIDs[i]).textContent = "something..."
}
```